# How do I show the difference between the last sale of a customer and the last/upper limit date shown in a slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the last sale date of a customer and the maximum date of a date range in slicer.

[image]

In the above screenshot, for a given customer ID, I have been able to isolate the most recent date the customer purchased in the time period defined by the slicer.

I want to be able to also show the number of days that have elapsed between the upper date limit shown in the slicer (April 30th 2023) and the last purchase date made by the customer (April 19th 2023).

However, any measure I create to show the upper limit date dependent on the slicer and not on the customer filters to show the most recent sale date for the customer. How do I remove this interaction such that I get the difference between the last sale date of the customer and the last date shown in the slicer?

Comment: If you have a slicer, it's adding a filter to the filter context of your measure. If you want to override that, You'd use a pattern like 

CALCULATE([Measure], 
ALL('DimDate'[Date]) 
)

to remove the Date from the evaluation context. (you may need to use FILTER( ALL('DimDate'[Date]), <add another filter here>) with your measure.